# Find count occurrences 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table with 2 columns (db: sql server 2008):

```
id         name
-----      ------
1          Bob
2          Mike
3          Mary
4          Mike
5          Barry
6          Benson
7          Burrows
```

I want to get a count of names that start with B and start with M (in one row)?

Like:

```
Count of B        Count of M
-----------      ------------
4                  3
```

The only thing that comes up for me is a union. Any ideas to do it cleaner in a single query (no union)?

Comment: I don't know how a union will get you two columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it by using `CASE`,

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(name,1,1) = 'B' Then 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(name,1,1) = 'M' Then 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM TAbleName
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/661555/5)

Comment: maybe add a where SUBSTRING(name,1,1) in ('B','M')

Answer (score 4):

You can use `PIVOT` for this.  If you have a known number of columns, then you can hard-code the values with a STATIC PIVOT:

```
select *
from
(
  select substring(name, 1, 1) name, -- use the same field twice, 
    substring(name, 1, 1) initial    -- once will be for the count the other for columns
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  count(name)
  for initial in ([B], [M])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/573ba/3)

If you have an unknown number of columns to transform, then you can use dynamic sql and create a Dynamic PIVOT:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                      + QUOTENAME(substring(name, 1, 1)) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
              select substring(name, 1, 1) name, 
                substring(name, 1, 1) initial
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(name)
                for initial in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b76f/1)

If you then want to filter the data set down to only those that begin with `B or M` then you can use a `WHERE` clause to filter.

```
where substring(name, 1, 1) in ('B', 'M')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way

```
Declare @T Table ([id] varchar(5), [name] varchar(7));

INSERT INTO @T([id], [name])
VALUES
    ('1', 'Bob'),
    ('2', 'Mike'),
    ('3', 'Mary'),
    ('4', 'Mike'),
    ('5', 'Barry'),
    ('6', 'Benson'),
    ('7', 'Burrows')

;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
    Initials = SUBSTRING(name,1,1)
    ,Cnt = COUNT([name]) 
FROM @t 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name,1,1))

SELECT 
    [Count of B] = (SELECT Cnt FROM CTE WHERE Initials = 'B')
    ,[Count of M] = (SELECT Cnt FROM CTE WHERE Initials = 'M')
```

**Result**

```
Count of B  Count of M
4             3
```